# The exact relationship between non-Euclidean Laguerre geometries and the planar algebras

Tags: reference-request, mobius-transformation, hypercomplex-numbers, cayley-klein

There are three planar hypercomplex number systems, which we shall denote $\mathbb C, \mathbb D, \mathbb R^2$. It is known that the *projective lines* over these number systems correspond to the Laguerre spears in elliptic, Euclidean and hyperbolic Laguerre geometries respectively. It is known that for each $A \in \{\mathbb C, \mathbb D, \mathbb R^2\}$, the corresponding *projective general linear group* $PGL_2(A)$ is isomorphic to the corresponding elliptic/Euclidean/hyperbolic Laguerre transformations which don't reverse orientation.

This is known, and there are ways to verify this using (let's say) Lie Sphere Geometry, or by decomposing the elements in $PGL_2(A)$, but what is the easiest way of seeing this? The material I've found so far is in German or Russian, by either Walter Benz or Isaak Yaglom. I'm requesting references.

Comment: You might like *The Geometry of Mobius Transformations* by Kisil.

Comment: I am not familiar with these things (beyond some browsing through Wikipedia), but I have a suspicion that they are related to the Clifford algebras $Cl_{3,0,0}, Cl_{2,0,1}, Cl_{2,1,0}$ over $\mathbb R$, where the subscripts indicate how many orthogonal vectors square to positive, negative, or zero. The centers of these algebras are exactly $\mathbb C, \mathbb D, \mathbb R^2$. [This PhD thesis](https://depositonce.tu-berlin.de/handle/11303/3355) by Charles Gunn is about their relationship to projective Cayley-Klein geometries (with a focus on the Euclidean case)...

Comment: ...This is certainly something I want to think more about. Do you know of a nice introduction to these Laguerre geometries, including the relation to $\mathbb C, \mathbb D, \mathbb R^2$?